# What is the significance of magnitude when we put a point in $ax+by+c$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

$$ax+by+c=0$$
If we put some point $(x,y)$ in the above equation $(ax+by+c)$ then the result could be either positive, negative or zero. I know the significance of the sign of the result, but does magnitude represent anything. For example $+5$ and $+20$ both represent that points lie on the same side but what is the significance of the magnitude?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The point with value 20 is four times as far from the line as the point with value 5 is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The significance of the magnitude is specifying the distance point from that line. With $ax+by+c=0$, the distance point $p(s,t)$ from the line is
$$D=\dfrac{|as+bt+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
as we see the denominator $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the same for all points, and the large magnitude of numerator detemine the large distance point $p$ from line.